# Obj-C, trying to remove some code from a view controller into a sub class?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Since I started developing my app, some of my view controllers have grown and now I have a lot of code in them. I'm just wondering if I could create some kind of subclass which would `inherit` instance variables, so I could move out some of the code.

I'm guessing this won't be possible, without creating a new class with properties, which I'll have to provide with values.

Is there anything neat I could do to save some time ?

Comment: Subclasses certainly do inherit ivars; that's how inheritance works. Can you be more specific about the problem you're facing?

Comment: Well my navigation dune button action, has a lot of code to evaluate input and format values. So lots of interface variables are used. I'd like to move this code into a new class ideally.

Comment: Please put some code into your question, instead of making general statements in comments.

Comment: If you can't solve this with `category` (see Ash Furrow's answer) then you're gonna have to subclass.

Comment: With categories, you don't even need to add the category to the `UIViewController` class; to validate forms, for instance, you could add a class method to the `UITextField` class. Post some code so we can help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pretty tricky and touchy subject with Objective-C coders. In general, this type of repletion is expected. You don't have any specifics in your question, but if you're only repeating some basic view setup code, that's not really an issue.

In general, creating a "base" `UIViewController` subclass is not common. If you're adding logic to your view controllers that's very common, like setting up a special navigation button, then you can use a [category](http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-categories.html).

Basically, in Objective-C, a category can be used to add a certain behaviour to *all instances* of some class. In the example I linked to, they add some functions to the string class. Take a look at what you're repeating and see if a category would be a better approach to subclassing.